# Receive SMS faster (SIM800)

Tags: sms, gsm, telecommunication

Is there a way to receive SMS messages sent to a GSM module (like sim800) as soon as the module boots up?

Usually if the SMS is sent while the receiving module is off, and then boots up the SMS messages take tens of minutes to arrive. However if the module is turned on, the messages arrive almost immediately.

Is there a way to signal the network that we are now connected and request all SMS messages?

I have tried network deregistration/registration (AT+COPS=2 AT+COPS=0) with no results

Comment: I don't think this is standardised so it will likely differ from operator to operators depending on the SMS solution they use and how they have it configured. Olaf's suggestion is something I have seen work also. It might be worth experimenting with different operators if you have the flexibility as you may find some have a shorter delay.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a lot of experience on this module, I believe this is rather a question about triggering the network provider to send SMS sooner (e.g. as soon as you're registered). This *might* depend on the network provider you're connecting to.

With a standard phone I've made the experience that triggering *some* network activity (e.g. calling someone or sending an SMS myself) seems to flush any SMS queues that they have waiting for me. You might try sending an SMS as soon as you're up

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it and it didnt work, I sent out some SMS messages but didnt receive the old SMS. I only received the old SMS when I sent a new one while GSM module was working.

Comment: Not sure we understood each other the same way: I thought of sending an sms as soon as the module is online *from* the module, not *to* it

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. 1) SMS to module while its offline. 2) powerup module, no incoming sms for 10 min. 3)I sent SMS from module, after 10 minutes still no incoming SMS. 4) then I send SMS to the module again while its online and immediately both messages came through.

Comment: In that case: try sending a message from the module to itself

Comment: no, curiously it doesn't work. The message I send to itself arrives immediately, but not the one sent to module while offline.

Answer (score 0):

Try Increasing The Baudrate 1000000 Preferably

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).